# Linq To Sql : add value transformation

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Consider the following expression:

```
from p in db.People
    select new Person {
        Name = p.Name, Age = p.Age, Gender = p.Gender.ToEnum<Gender>()
};
```

It works to the point of calling extension method `static T ToEnum<T>(this string value);` as expected.
I understand why there is **do not know how to translate string to enum** error.
**Question is:** how do I work around this without introducing another class?
I mean that I could define class `PersonWithGenderAsText` and then translate that into `Person` class, but I feel there got to be an easier way.
Specifically, I don't mind calling `.ToList()` on the result of the expression above, but I cant figure out the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an anonymous inner type to fetch just the bits you want from the database, use AsEnumerable to switch to "in process" mode, and *then* you can do the transformation into a Person object:

```
var query = db.People
              .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Age, p.Gender } )
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(p => new Person { Name = p.Name,
                                        Age = p.Age,
                                        Gender = p.Gender.ToEnum<Gender>() } );
```

If there's no more data in `db.People` you could simplify this further:

```
var query = db.People
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(p => new Person { Name = p.Name,
                                        Age = p.Age,
                                        Gender = p.Gender.ToEnum<Gender>() } );
```